signal store feature displays error when adding new entity
I have the following signal store feature that uses Entity, and I'm getting an error when adding an entity. I need support with resolving it:
screenshot picture
This is the signal store feature:
const recordConfig = entityConfig({
  collection: 'records',
  entity: type<Record>,
  selectId: (record) => record().pid,
});

export function withRecord() {
  return signalStoreFeature(
    withEntities(recordConfig),
    withMethods((store, campaignAPI = inject(CampaignAPI)) => ({
      appendRecord(
        campaignPID: number,
        ctpid: number,
        recordData: RecordGetResponseModel
      ): Record {
        const record: Record = {
          pid: ctpid,
          campaignPID: campaignPID,
          data: recordData,
        };

        patchState(store, addEntity(record, recordConfig));
        return record;
      },
    }))
  );
}


I found the issue, from the whole time I defined entity type wrong, missed to add parenthesis at the end.
const recordConfig = entityConfig({
  collection: 'records',
  entity: type<Record>(),
  selectId: (record) => record().pid,
});

